# modificar un diccionario que esta en un lista que tiene varios diccionarios

Tags: python, diccionarios

```
huevo =[ 
{"tipo_huevos": "A", "numero_huevos": 0, "numero_bandejas": 0},
{"tipo_huevos": "AA", "numero_huevos": 0, "numero_bandejas": 0},
{"tipo_huevos": "AAA", "numero_huevos": 0, "numero_bandejas": 0},
{"tipo_huevos": "BC", "numero_huevos": 0, "numero_bandejas": 0}
]

entrada=float(input("ingrese el peso de cada huevo: "))
while entrada != 0:
    if entrada >0 and entrada<53:
```

> como le digo aquí que le sume 1 a "numero_huevos" del tipo A?    +=1

```
    elif entrada <60:
        
    elif entrada <67:
        
    else:
        
    entrada=float(input("ingrese el peso de cada huevo: "))
```

necesito ayuda para sumarle datos a los diccionarios que estan en la lista

Comment: Tienes que recorrer la lista por ejemplo `for d in huevo`, y así `d` sería cada uno de los diccionarios. Entonces puedes hacer `if d["tipo_huevos"]=="A": d["numero_huevos"]+=1`

Comment: muchas gracias y al momento de imprimir la lista como se haría para que esta salga ordenada? digamos:
dic1.......
dic2......
dic3.....
una debajo de la otra y no en una sola linea
y que no salgan las [ ] " " ni { } ?

Comment: @Juancarlosplata de igual forma la tendrias que recorrer